# printing character on screen with putchar

Tags: c++

```
void main ()
{
char ch='A';
while (ch <='F'){
switch (ch){
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C':
case 'D': ch++; continue;
case 'E';
case 'F': ch++;
}
putchar (ch);

}
```

My question is, why the program's output is only FG,  why it doesn't print the letter E (EFG). And also, why does putchar print two character's when the definition of putchar is that it print's only one character on the screen.

Comment: `case 'E';` - cannot be even compiled.

Comment: Perhaps you should [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? That way you can, with the help of a debugger, step through your code line by line to see what it does.

Comment: I have a sense of a re-asked question.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to case  E,  since there is no  break; after that statement it will execute every case after it in the switch statement thus doing  ch++;  of the case F
  E++ is F so putchar will print F 
Next since your condition in the while statement is less or equal to F it will enter again the switch
 In case F it will do again ch++ now ch holds the value of G and putchar prints G 
G is not less or equal F, it exits the while loop and ends.
So you have printed F then G.

Answer (score -1):

To the question why E isn't printed take a look at the comments i made to your code here:

```
void main ()
{
char ch='A';
while (ch <='F'){
switch (ch){
case 'A': // ch: A=>B; continue;
case 'B': // ch: B=>C; continue;
case 'C': // ch: C=>D; continue;
case 'D': ch++; continue; // ch: D=>E; continue; | E isn't printed here "continue" is called instead.
case 'E'; // ch: E=>F; putchar(F); | E isn't printed here either F is printed because F is assigned just before "putchar" is called.
case 'F': ch++; // ch: F=>G; putchar(G);
}
putchar (ch);

}
```

The second question, why putchar prints two character:
It doesn't. It only writes one char to the output buffer each time but the output buffer is written to screen on late calls.

Use `std::cout.flush()` after putchar to display your output immediately.

Also change `case 'E';` to `case 'E':` to make your code compilable, please.